# "an hour" vs "for an hour"

Tags: prepositions, time

Are both "**I have been reading an hour already**" and "**I have been reading for an hour already**" correct?

Or "**I have been working here 3 years**" and "**I have been working here for 3 years**"?

Answer (score 2):

> I have been reading **for** an hour already.
>   I have been working here **for** 3 years.

using **for** sounds more *natural* and *native*, though in *conversation*

> I have been here an hour, waiting for you.
>   *I have been here for an hour waiting for you.*

might be heard.

Comment: Haha - your *waiting* example mirrors the comment I was making as you posted this answer. I'm pretty sure the preposition is less likely to be dropped in contexts like *He's been sick **for** a week* than, say, *He's been waiting a week* (though that second context might be influenced by the fact that you might say *He's been waiting for a week for a doctor's appointment,* and some people might balk at the repetition).

Comment: I think the **for** my get dropped in that instance because the phrase gets used so often, and you're right it's strongly associated with the *passage of time*. One case when **for** would never be dropped: "I've been waiting **for bloody ever** for you!"

Comment: Sick a week, dead a week, waiting a week, very common in AmE, and I'd venture to say in other dialects as well.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: The difference isn't as large as I might have expected, but check out [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+waiting+a+week%2Cbeen+waiting+for+a+week&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20waiting%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20waiting%20for%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0) showing that the preposition is usually *not* included in the sequence *been **waiting** a week*...

Comment: ...conversely, it usually *is* included in [*been **sick for** a week*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=been+sick+a+week%2Cbeen+sick+for+a+week&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeen%20sick%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbeen%20sick%20for%20a%20week%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That's in writing.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo: What difference does *that* make? I'll admit it's not an *extreme* preference, but those charts certainly suggest that the choice of whether or not to include ***for*** varies according to the *specific type* of activity or state being referenced. Would you have it that *writers* are consciously observing a syntactic principle that *speakers* are either unaware of, or choose to ignore? That seems unlikely to me. A tendency is a tendency.

Comment: The Ngram corpus is OK for showing large trends and for finding attestations of a particular usage, but not so good for answering more nuanced questions. With respect to your claim that verbs with strong associations with 'passage of time' are more likely not to use **for** , the Ngram evidence is inconclusive. http://tinyurl.com/ybsaawbp  I only point this out because you frequently make such statements about relative frequency of use, based on truly inconclusive evidence.